# DataGridView & datasource will not clear

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that receives its information from a BindingList. When the program runs, the DGV should appear completely blank with no row data whatsoever. However, it instead creates a row with a couple values in some of the cells. In my Form startup, I've included

```
ExpenseList = new BindingList<ExpenseReportBackBone>();            
            dataGridViewPurchaseData.DataSource = ExpenseList;
            ExpenseList.Clear();
            dataGridViewPurchaseData.Rows.Clear();
```

to try and empty it out, but it still appears as the screenshot shows. 
Why is this not opening to a blank DGV?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set `AllowUsersToAddRows` to false in the `DataGridView`?

Comment: Ok yeah doing that fixed it. That's weird that this affects it that way... if you wanna post below I can mark an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AllowUsersToAddRows` is set to true as the default setting for the `DataGridView` and what you are seeing is the newly added row.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know why its not empty when you run the program ,but try to clear it
first null the data source:

```
this.dataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

and after clear rows

```
this.dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

if you are using BindingList

```
DataGrid.DataSource = null;
DataGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: its to make the datagrid empty , when he run the program its not empty cause there is something on load form that shoud be removed

Comment: Look at the user's code — they created a new list, so it's already empty.  Setting the DataSource to null will remove the columns.  `DataBind();` is for ASP, not WinForms.